# About pointer declaration

Tags: c

I'm playing with pointers and a can't get why this declaration is fine

```
char *ptr = "Hey"
```

but this is wrong

```
int  *ptr = 10;
```

Can any one explain ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The correct analogy would be that the following two are *both* wrong:

```
char * p = 'a';  // error
int  * q = 123;  // error
```

Here you are trying to assign a value of some type to a variable that is a *pointer* to a variable of that type.

By contrast, the following are correct:

```
int  tmp_a[] = { 10, 20, 30 };
char tmp_b[] = { 'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '\0' };

int  * p = tmp_a;
char * q = tmp_b;
```

The string literal `"hello"` is an anonymous, read-only array of characters, of identical content as `tmp_b`, so it can be interpreted as a pointer to its first element. Since the character data is read-only, the correct definition should be this:

```
const char * r = "hello";  // r[0] - r[5] have the same value as q[0] - q[5]
```

Comment: It should be made clear that string literals (in C) are read-only, but are _not_ `const`. This is probably a Bad Thing, and only exists for legacy code, and C++ fixes it.

Comment: @ChrisLutz: You're right, the *type* of `"hello"` is only `char[6]` in C, not `const char[6]`, but any attempt to modify the elements is UB -- so it's best to declare this as const right away. I'll edit this to "should be", though.

Comment: This tool will automatically generate explanations of C pointer syntax (it looks useful for this purpose): http://cdecl.org/

Answer (score 4):

Simply put `10` is not an `int*`, rather it is an `int`. You cannot assign an `int` to a pointer since they are different things.

The code `char *ptr = "Hey"` succeeds because string literals are assignment compatible with `char*` pointers.

Note however that  `char *ptr = "Hey"` has the effect of making `ptr` point to a string literal. String literals are generally stored in read-only memory so any attempts to modify them fail. So you would be better to write  `const char *ptr = "Hey"`.

Answer (score 1):

Strings in C are defined as `char *`. Otherwise, if you want to have a single character you'd use `char var = 'x';`.

`int  *ptr = 10;` is *not* "wrong", it legally sets your pointer to the address '10', which is, in most (if not all) cases, out of the memory bounds of your application.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: No, it's wrong to implicitly cast an integer constant (other than 0) to a pointer type.

Comment: @Chris in that setting `0` is not an integer constant.

Comment: @Chris: This is C not C++ so 0 is also invalid.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - Not to nitpick, but the standard appears to indicate that it's also an integer. (I wouldn't normally look this up but I have a paper to procrastinate.)

Comment: @Skizz - 0 as a null pointer constant isn't invalid in C, people do it all the time. C allows `0` or `(void *)0`; C++ only allows `0` due to the stronger typing.

Comment: Strings in C are *defined* as a sequence of characters followed by a terminating 0; they are *stored* as arrays of `char`.  In most contexts, an array expression (such as a string literal) will be converted to a pointer expression whose value is the address of the first element in the array, which is why the initialization works.

Answer (score 0):

In C, `"Hey"` is defined as an anonymous array of characters, so memory is allocated to store the character values (four of them, there's a null terminator as well).

Also, you can only point to things that are in memory. So the `char *` can point to the anonymous array of characters.

The value `10` is just a value. It has no memory assigned to it. You cannot get the address of something that's not in memory. So the `int *` fails.

To get the second to work, you need to allocate some memory:

```
int value = 10;
int *ptr = &value; // value is in memory so we can point to it
```

Answer (score 0):

In the first case, `"Hey"` is a string literal, it has the type `char *`. Hence, it is OK to initialize `ptr` that way. Having said that, it *really* should be as follow as string literals can't be written to:

```
char const * ptr = "Hey";
```

On the other hand, it you declare something like:

```
int * ptr = ...;
```

You define a pointer that should point to an integer. As `10` is a plain integer constant, it is not an existing int object, you can't point to it. However, you can write something like:

```
int intValue;
int * ptr = &intValue;
```

In this case `intValue` is an object that you can point to.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that string literals like `"Hey"` are special. They are stored somewhere in memory, and are constant.

Assigning a pointer to `"Hey"` will actually create that string in the constants, and assign to `ptr` the address of this constant.

However, when you have an `int* ptr`, assigning to `10` will assign the address `10`, whereas you meant the address of the integer of value `10`.

Answer (score 0):

To put it it simple. When the compiler sees the string "Hey" in

```
char *ptr = "Hey"
```

the compiler will save the characters Hey plus a zero terminating byte in memory and then it will replace the "Hey" string with a pointer to the first character in the string.

In

```
int  *ptr = 10;
```

it will not convert the 10 to a pointer. It will see the 10 as an integer and complain that it is not the same type as ptr - a pointer to an int.